# WPF ComboBox Popup template with border changing background color every system color changes

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, popup, ivalueconverter

I have here my customized `ComboBox`:

[image]

It's actually a browser selection. But right now what you see there is a prototype of the selector control using `ComboBox`.

The problem I am having is this dropdown (`Popup`) control background

[image]

The background color should dynamically change once the user change their theme color in `Color and Apperance` setting in `Personalization`.

This is the story behind my template

I am able to change the `Background` color using a simple `Converter`:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    int argbColor = (int)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM", "ColorizationColor", null);
    var color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(argbColor);

    SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush();

    if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 6 && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor == 1) // Windows 7
    {
        //scb = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb((byte)((int)color.A / 3), color.R, color.G, color.B));
        scb = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B));
    }
    else if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 6 && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor == 2) // Windows 8 
    {
        scb = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B));
    }

    return scb;
}
```

set it up like this:

```
<me:BackgroundConverter x:Key="BgConverter" />
```

and implement it like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" Grid.Column="0" AllowsTransparency="true" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
            <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent">
                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" 
                    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" 
                    BorderThickness="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BorderConverter}}" 
                    Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BgConverter}}" 
                    CornerRadius="0,0,12,12">

                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="bn" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>
        <ToggleButton Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton}"/>
        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

check the `Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"` line. Now how do I make it dynamically change when a user changes their theme color? I tried via Trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="true">
    <!-- not really working -->
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BgConverter}}"/>
</Trigger>
```

but it's not working

I actually have a pretty simple lame solution by hooking onto `DropDownOpened` or `DropDownClosed` events and just change the background color from there. That solution is actually working pretty well but there may be a simplest way of doing it via Trigger or EventTrigger?

-- UPDATE --

```
public static class ComboBoxExtension
{
    public static void UpdatePopupBackground(this ComboBox cb)
    {
        Border b = (Border)cb.Template.FindName("DropDownBorder", cb);

        int argbColor = (int)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM", "ColorizationColor", null);
        var color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(argbColor);

        SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush();

        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 6 && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor == 1) // Windows 7
        {
            //scb = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb((byte)((int)color.A / 3), color.R, color.G, color.B));
            scb = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B));
        }
        else if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 6 && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor == 2) // Windows 8 
        {
            scb = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B));
        }

        b.Background = scb;
    }
}
```

and call it when the DropDownOpened triggers:

```
ComboMe.UpdatePopupBackground();
```

LOL... well..

Comment: Why are you not setting your SCB in the converter like `scb = new SolidColorBrush(color);`? Is your Converter ever entered?

Comment: Yes Florian, perfectly executed.

Comment: That one on the trigger is just a test. That can be omitted. Sorry for the confusion. Let me remove that on on the trigger.

Comment: Does the color change if youre using the trigger and set a random color in the converter?

Comment: No it doesn't. The color change only once from "Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BgConverter}}" in Border

Comment: Then try removing `"Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BgConverter}}"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23706/discussion-between-jayson-ragasa-and-florian-gl)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the first step to get notified of this particular color change, you'll need to hook the WindowProc in MainWindow (or a hidden color-change-detection window?) and watch for the WM_DWMCOLORIZATIONCOLORCHANGED message from the DWM.